# Is there a way to have reusable pathing for imports on Go projects?

Tags: git, go, path-finding

I am very new at Go, and need a bit of help with a way to make import pathing more distributable between my team.

Currently at the top of one of my Go files, I have an import, say "github.teamName.com/teamMemberA/HeartThrob/c"

I forked his project to my own name and downloaded it and got some pretty obvious import errors.

MY path to the file it is trying to import is the following: "github.teamName.com/myName/HeartThrob/c"

This pathing change is because I am pulling the project from my own forked repo.

What is a way I can go about fixing this? Is relative pathing possible? I can't put all the Go files into the same directory due to the size of the project and some obvious places for separation.

Disclaimer: New to Go AND Git (My forked approach is team-mandated though)

Comment: Bummer. Then maybe check out `/myname/appname` into `$GOPATH/src/orgname/appname` (or whatever path corresponds to the master URL), and do your work there. If you need to work with multiple forks, switch GOPATHs or swap them out via mv, etc.

Comment: The flow sucks a little then (at a minimum, you can't just use "go get" anymore) but if your team mandates you work on forks I don't see anything better. Maybe someone'll answer with something better, though.

Comment: Yeah checking out my fork into the file path relating to the main fork fixed it. Good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that GOPATH contains a single element, do this:

```
$ mkdir -p $GOPATH/github.teamName.com/teamMemberA
$ cd $GOPATH/github.teamName.com/teamMemberA
$ git clone github.teamName.com/myName/HeartThrob
$ cd HeartThrob/c
$ go install
```

An alternative approach is:

```
$ go get github.teamName.com/teamMemberA/HeartThrob/c
$ cd $GOPATH/github.teamName.com/teamMemberA/HeartThrob
$ git remote add fork git@github.myName/HeartThrob.git
```

Hack a way and push to fork.

Comment: Yes! This is it. Even though my forked version has a different path, I can ignore that by simply building the file structure that complies with the import paths. Good answer (your first suggestion worked smoothly)