# How to merge similar multi-package projects in go

Tags: go, gopath

Several organizations distribute variants of the same project, and we regularly pull changes from one another.  It would be great if we could eventually merge code repositories and maybe, maybe have a common source tree managed by a consortium.  However, each member would probably want the option of distributing their own variant without too much pain for customers in case there is trouble upstreaming changes required to work with newer products.

The project consists of three packages:

1. A library
2. A compiler executable that outputs go code that needs to import the library
3. A utility executable that uses code generated by #2 and links with #1

A big annoyance, when pulling changes back and forth, is gratuitous differences in import paths.  We basically have to edit every version of `import "github.com/companyA/whatever"` to `import "companyB.com/whatever"`.  Of course these problems would go away with (gasp) relative import paths.  If we resorted to such heresy, our compiler can just hard-code the absolute import path in generated code to isolate end users from the library's import path.  It would also require only one gratuitous difference in the source trees (the line in the compiler that outputs import statements) rather than a bunch.

But anyway, I know relative import paths are bad - this is a tricky situation.  I know this is similar to questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510180/is-there-a-way-to-have-reusable-pathing-for-imports-on-go-projects) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166642/how-to-handle-go-import-absolute-paths-and-github-forks), because the answer of just asking end users to create a directory called `companyB.com` and cloning something from `companyA` in there is just not going to fly for practical and political reasons.

I already know that go is not really good at accommodating this scenario, so I'm also not asking for a magic bullet to make go handle something it can't.  Another thing that unfortunately won't fly is asking customers to `curl whatever | sh`, as this is viewed as too much of a liability (deemed "training customers to do dangerous things").  Maybe we could forego `go get` and have everyone clone to some neutral non-DNS-name under `$GOPATH/src`, but we would need to do this without a "flag day" in which code suddenly breaks if it's in the wrong place.

My question is whether anyone has successfully merged SDK-type projects with existing end users, and if so, how did you do it, what worked, and what didn't?  Did you in fact avoid relative import paths or gnarly `GOPATH` hacking, and if so was it worth it?  What mechanisms did you employ (environment variables, configuration files, `.project-config` files in the current working directory, abusing the `vendor` directory, code-generation packages that figure out their absolute import path at compliation time) to make this work smoothly?  Did you just muddle through with a huge amount of `sed` or maybe `gofmt -r`?  Are there tricks involving clever use of `.gitattributes` or `go generate` to rewrite import paths on checkout/checkin?

Comment: It's not that "relative import paths are bad", relative imports are not allowed and do not work in GOPATH at all.

Answer (score 1):

Merging them is pretty easy - cross-merge so that they all match, pick one (or create a new one) as the canonical source of truth, then migrate all references to the canonical import and make all future updates there.

The probablem arises here:

> each member would probably want the option of distributing their own variant without too much pain for customers in case there is trouble upstreaming changes required to work with newer products

There's no particularly good way to do that without using any of the known solutions you've already ruled out, and no way to do that depending on your threshold for "too much pain".

Without knowing more about the situation it's hard to suggest options, but if there's any way that each company can abstract their portion out into a separate library they could maintain and update at their pace while using a smaller shared library with shared responsibility, that would likely be the best option - something like the model used by [Terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/) for its providers? Basically you'd have shared maintenance of a shared "core" and then independent maintenance of "vendor-specific" packages.

Comment: Thanks for the link to terraform.  That does indeed provide a good model to strive for, the question is how to get there.  I'm not sure what you mean about cross-merge, but if this involves some kind of flag day for all but one company, that seems pretty tricky.  I think we probably need a period of at least few months to migrate people from the old paths to the new path, unless maybe we make the project "self-migrating" (for which I'd love to hear some experience).

Comment: Further complicating the matter is getting buy-in.  Most engineers I think want to merge, but we probably need to get the source trees as close as possible to make this happen, as it could involve other issues like branding that people don't really want to think about until the code is basically unified.